# Как неявно подключить DLL к консольному приложению в VS 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012

Пробую подключить но выдаёт ошибку.
Вот проект Lab6_SP_dll в котором написана библиотека.

Заголовочный файл

```
//mydll.h
#ifndef _DLLTEST_H_
#define _DLLTEST_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CounterLetter(string X, string Y);
#endif
```

cpp.-файл

```
//mydll.cpp
#include "mydll.h"
#define MAXMODULE 50

char module[MAXMODULE];

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CounterLetter(string X, string Y) {
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)module, MAXMODULE);
    cout << "This function was called from " << module << endl;
    int counter = 0;
    if(X.length()==Y.length()){
        for(int i = 0; i < X.length(); i++){
            if(X[i]==Y[i])
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Вот проект Lab6_main в котором пытаюсь использовать библиотеку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "C:\Users\_имя_пользователя_\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Lab6_SP_dll\Lab6_SP_dll\mydll.h"

void main()
{
    string X;
    string Y;
    while(true){
        cout << "Enter string X: ";
        cin >> X;
        cout << "\nEnter string Y: ";
        cin >> Y;
        if(CounterLetter(X, Y) != -1){
            cout << "Same letters:" << CounterLetter(X, Y);
            break;
        }
        else cout <<"Strings have different lenghts! Try again.\n";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Вот ошибки которые выдаёт компилятор:

```
Ошибка  1   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _CounterLetter в функции _main
Ошибка  2   error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: У вас `__declspec` не правильно определен в консольном приложении, в библиотеке он должен быть `dllexport`, а в консольном как `dllimport`. А неявная загрузка, это `LoadLibrary` и т.д.

Comment: как правильно написать dllimport ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно було положить `Lab6_SP_dll.dll` в папку с `Lab6_SP_main.exe`, а код в проекте `Lab6_SP_main` изменить на слудующий

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#pragma comment (lib, "C:\\Users\\_имя_пользователя_\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Lab6_SP_dll\\Debug\\Lab6_SP_dll.lib")
#include "C:\Users\_имя_пользователя_\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Lab6_SP_dll\Lab6_SP_dll\mydll.h"

void main()
{
    string X;
    string Y;
    while(true){
        cout << "Enter string X: ";
        cin >> X;
        cout << "\nEnter string Y: ";
        cin >> Y;
        if(CounterLetter(X, Y) != -1){
            cout << "Same letters:" << CounterLetter(X, Y);
            break;
        }
        else cout <<"Strings have different lenghts! Try again.\n";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Где через `#pragma comment (lib, "C:\\Users\\_имя_пользователя_\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Lab6_SP_dll\\Debug\\Lab6_SP_dll.lib")` указан путь к сгенерированому `.lib` файл.

Вместо строки  `#pragma comment (lib, "C:\\Users\\_имя_пользователя_\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Lab6_SP_dll\\Debug\\Lab6_SP_dll.lib")` можно добавить зависимость через "свойства->ввод->дополнительные зависимости" и добавить собственно эту зависимость.

Answer (score 0):

Самое просто решение это определение макроса в файле `mydll.h`

```
#define IS_DLL 1
#if IS_DLL == 1
#    define API_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define API_EXPORT __declspec(dllomport)
#endif
```

Далее после `#include "C:\Users\Taras Viiatyk\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Lab6_SP_dll\Lab6_SP_dll\mydll.h"`

переопределите макрос на `0`

```
#define IS_DLL 0
```

Измените ваш файл mydll.h вот так:

```
#ifndef _DLLTEST_H_
#define _DLLTEST_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" API_EXPORT int CounterLetter(string X, string Y);
#endif
```

И файл mydll.cpp на

```
//mydll.cpp
#include "mydll.h"
#define MAXMODULE 50

char module[MAXMODULE];

int CounterLetter(string X, string Y) {
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)module, MAXMODULE);
    cout << "This function was called from " << module << endl;
    int counter = 0;
    if(X.length()==Y.length()){
        for(int i = 0; i < X.length(); i++){
            if(X[i]==Y[i])
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

В дополнении не забудьте добавить ссылку на проект с библиотекой в ваш основной проект.

Исходя из вашего заголовка вопроса о неявном подключении, используйте функции `WinApi` [LoadLibrary](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya), [GetProcAddress](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) и определение прототипа функции из библиотеки.

Далее ваша программа будет выглядеть вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef int(*CounterLetterFunc)(string X, string Y);

void main()
{
    HMODULE module = LoadLibraryA("PathToDll.dll");
    CounterLetterFunc myExportFunc = GetProcAddress(module, "CounterLetter");
    string X;
    string Y;
    while(true){
        cout << "Enter string X: ";
        cin >> X;
        cout << "\nEnter string Y: ";
        cin >> Y;
        if(myExportFunc(X, Y) != -1){
            cout << "Same letters:" << myExportFunc(X, Y);
            break;
        }
        else cout <<"Strings have different lenghts! Try again.\n";
    }
    FreeLibrary(module);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: по моему мой вариант проще)